# Is it possible to get monthly stock prices from Google Finance?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python, monthly stock prices from Yahoo Finance as follows...

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web

data = web.get_data_yahoo('IBM','01/01/2016',interval='m')
```

I tried to get monthly stock prices from Google Finance, but daily stock prices are returned

```
data = web.get_data_google('IBM','2016')
```

How can I get monthly stock prices from Google Finance in Python ?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#google-finance), this is indeed possible.

EDIT: The example below, despite being part of the documentation, does not seem to work. I have found that the following works as an alternative:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
quotes = web.DataReader('NYSE:IBM', 'google')
```

Where `'NYSE:IBM'` is the exchange code and ticker separated by a colon, and `'google'` is the pricing source.

OLD (NON-WORKING) EXAMPLE:

```
In [42]: import pandas_datareader.data as web

In [43]: q = web.get_quote_google(['AMZN', 'GOOG'])

In [44]: q
Out[44]: 
      change_pct    last                time
AMZN        0.01  780.22 2016-11-25 13:00:00
GOOG        0.09  761.68 2016-11-25 13:00:00
```

Comment: thanks, but I do not know  'GOOG' meaning....and the error occured

>>> import pandas_datareader.data as web
>>> q = web.get_quote_google(['AMZN', 'GOOG'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    q = web.get_quote_google(['AMZN', 'GOOG'])
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\google\quotes.py", line 10, in _get_data
    raise NotImplementedError(msg)
NotImplementedError: Google Finance doesn't have this functionality - can't get quote for ['AMZN', 'GOOG']

Comment: 'GOOG' is a ticker. so is 'AMZN'.